# Pointer addition check

Tags: c, pointers

I have a few questions about pointers.

I have the following struct

```
struct buffer {
    char *ptr;
    char data[DATA_SIZE];
};
```

and I have the following code

```
printk("ptrs and what not:  buf=%p, b-ptr=%p,   b-data=%p,    INIT_LOC=%lu\n", buf, buf->ptr, buf->data, INIT_LOC);

if (buf)
    buf->ptr = buf->data + INIT_LOC;

printk("ptrs and what not:  buf=%p, b-ptr=%p,   b-data=%p,    INIT_LOC=%lu\n", buf, buf->ptr, buf->data, INIT_LOC);
```

The output is the following:

```
ptrs and what not:  buf=ffff880091ae2000, b-ptr=          (null),   b-data=ffff880091ae2008,    INIT_LOC=10
ptrs and what not:  buf=ffff880091ae2000, b-ptr=ffff880091ae2012,   b-data=ffff880091ae2008,    INIT_LOC=10
```

questions

1) when adding a number, lets say 2  to a ptr with an address lets say 10001
is the value 10003, or 10001 + 2 * sizeof(X), where x is the type of the ptr.

2) if ptr=10001 is an array of chars in memory, the first character in that array is at location 10001, is the second character at location 10002 or 10009? or what would it be?

3) going to the printout shown above the buf->data has address 2008, i am not sure how adding 10 to it makes it point to 2012.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, thanks, not sure how i missed it :D

Comment: All of these questions you can find the answers for. By **trying** yourself...

Comment: You could populate `data` with some dummy data, then set `ptr` equal to the first position in the `data` array, then print out what `ptr+1` gives you versus `ptr+3` gives you, for instance. That would probably answer your questions.

Comment: You left out the rarely-talked-about, but equally-important contrapositive to pointer-incrementing: pointer *differencing*.  Given two pointers `Type *a,*b` assigned to different locations in a contiguous region:`Type ar[10]; a=ar+1; b=ar+5;` the pointer *difference* also accounts for `sizeof(Type)` as a byte-count-divisor rather than a multiplier. I.e. in the case here, no matter what `Type` is, `int n = (b - a);` will always be 4; *not* a byte-count (unless `sizeof(Type)` is 1, of course). This comes in *very* handy in certain sorting algorithms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `10001 + 2 * sizeof(X)`
2. `10002`
3. It's in hex, 0x2012-0x2008 equals 10 in decimal.

Comment: so for question 2, the address is pointing to bytes? so character A is at 10001 and B would be at 10002, and the char size is 1 byte in C?

Comment: `sizeof` actually returns the size in multiples of char size, but you can assume 1 char == 1 byte on sane platforms

Comment: @Kos `sizeof(type)` returns number of bytes that comprise `type`

Comment: @icepack BTW are there any implementations where 'byte' (defined as "unit large enough to hold any member of the basic character set") would be more than 8 bits? Just curious

Comment: @Kos seems that it has been standardized to 8 bits so any other size would be invalid: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte

Comment: A few embedded DSP processors have chars of 16 or 32 bits. (see e.g. http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/TI_Compilers_and_Industry_Standards)

Answer (score 2):

> 1) when adding a number, lets say 2 to a ptr with an address lets say 10001 is the value 10003, or 10001 + 2 * sizeof(X), where x is the type of the ptr.

Addition and subtraction moves the pointer X *elements* forth or back. This prevents you from having a mis-aligned pointer that points to the middle of a multi-byte object. *(Unless you're doing invalid casts between pointer types).*

> 2) if ptr=10001 is an array of chars in memory, the first character in that array is at location 10001, is the second character at location 10002 or 10009? or what would it be?

10002, since `sizeof(char)` is 1.

> 3) going to the printout shown above the buf->data has address 2008, i am not sure how adding 10 to it makes it point to 2012

Notice the hexadecimal notation.

Comment: well and `data` in its current state will give you garbage without initialization.

Comment: sizeof(char) is 1. Ok. But: does this guarantee that the representation of a pointer, shown with %p, is in the same granularity? Or could it be smaller? (Bits, for example)?

Answer (score 0):

1) Both are wrong. X is the type of the pointee.

2) Unless your architecture can adress something smaller than a char, it should be 10002.

3) 0x2008 + 10 = 0x2012